# How can I fire my own mouse hover event when default tooltip of chart is used?

Tags: c#, winforms, hover, tooltip

I'm relatively new to C# and winform please help me.

I'm using MS Chart and set Tooltip text to all series.

What I want to do is to fire my own mouse hover event in chart class.

I found out that my hover event is able to works with disabled series's tooltip!

But I set tooltip, I am able to get only toolip without hover event..

plz help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post some code showing what you've done so far.

Comment: Are you looking for [`GetToolTipText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.gettooltiptext(v=vs.110).aspx) event?

Comment: I have read the question 3 times but I don't understand. Show us what (if any) you have coded in the MouseHover event. Tell us what works and what doesn't. Tell us what you want from the UI perspective, not from the coding perspective so you don't fall into the x-y-problem trap..